# Transition of color change hover also affects display none when applied

Tags: css

I'm animating the hover color change on links. This is working fine:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>

 a { 
   transition: color 0.4s linear;
 }
a {
    color: red;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNNvNL

However I'm having an issue with I use Javascript to show and hide links by adding a class set to `display: none;` Instead of being hidden straight away there is a delay (the length of the animation) before the link is hidden.

This is strange as I've only told the link to transition its color. Is this a bug or by design?

UPDATE In  my example ive used links but in my actual site links and buttons are styled the same.

Comment: Could you share an example of the `display:none` with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason explicitly setting display none on the class and the element fixed this.

```
// This along isnt sufficient:
.hide {
  display: none;
}

// Adding this makes it work: 
button.hide {
  display: none;
}
```